# How is Chatzos Halayla (Halachic Midnight) calculated?

Tags: zemanim, tikkun-chatzot, chatzos

It seems pretty easy to calculate from the get-go that the formula is something like this:

```
# a halachic hour is one twelfth of the time between sunrise and sunset
halachicHour = (timeOfSunset - timeOfSunrise) / 12 
# thus chatzos halayla would be literally 
chatzosHalayla = timeOfSunset + (halachicHour * 6)
```

Above, a halachic hour is determined by the distance from sunrise to sunset divided by twelve.

This makes things interesting, as I presume that often "midnight" doesn't exactly happen in the middle of the night (period between nightfall and sunrise or dawn). How, then, do we calculate Chatzos Halayla?

I was reading a book on Tikkun Chatzos recently which sparked my interest in this. According to the author, Rebbe Nachman of Breslov calculated the middle of the night by adding six *civil* hours to nightfall, but this doesn't make any sense and I believe that the author is making an assumption about this. It would make sense to say that Rebbe Nachman calculated the middle of the night using six *halachic* hours, but  to use six *civil* hours doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: My understanding is that Rebbe Nachman zy'a rules this way to make things easier to calculate.  He may be basing himself on the Mechaber as is general practice in Breslev.

Comment: His cheshbon is: take tzeis hakochavim and add a quarter of a me'eis l'eis. What's wrong with that?

Comment: In Book "The Sweetest Hour" by A. Greenbaum, author says that Rabbi Nachman's opinion is according to MA in OC 1:2 and 233:1.

Answer (score 6):

The Shulchan Aruch Harav ([1:8 in the Mahadura Basra](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&pgnum=34)) says that Chatzos is calculated by finding chatzos hayom and adding 12 (civil) hours to it.

Answer (score 0):

At night, an halachic hour is a twelfth of the difference found when you subtract the time of sunset from the time of sunrise, not vice versa. (I have no source for this, though.)

Comment: So, in any case, chatzos halayla would be caculated as being six halachic hours into the night?

Comment: My Zmanim app for my phone (using the library provided by KosherJava) calculates Chatzos Halayla and Chatzos Hayom as being 12:46 am and pm, respectively.

Comment: Re "in any case...": There are differences of opinion as to when _chatzos_ (day or night) is. IIRC Rabbi _Moshe_ Feinstein's view is that _chatzos_ (or at least one of them) is constant (over the course of a year for any given location), which would not fit in with its being 6 hours into the night. I don't know (or don't recall) what particular constant he said it is, though. `:-/` Perhaps someone else can answer better. Re "12:46 am and pm": _If chatzos_ is 6 hours into the night/day, then they will be 12 hours apart (plus or minus about a minute) on any given day just because of arithmetic.

Comment: @msh210, R. Moshe's view is that chatzos hayom is when the sun crosses the local meridian (solar noon); this is constant in any given place throughout the year (except for the shift due to daylight savings time), and it can be expressed as (longitude * 4 - offset from GMT) minutes before 12:00 PM (or after, if the result is negative). In New York, for example, it's 11:56 AM standard time. Presumably, then, he'd say that chatzos halailah is the same thing - when the sun crosses the antipodal meridian, exactly 12 clock hours later.